# How to add button on Outgoing Call Screen in Android

Tags: android, call, android-button

I am trying to add a button or option menu on outgoing call screen
I have tried this code but its showing a fatal error kindly verify the code

```
public class CustomOutgoingCallActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new OutgoingReciver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
```

public class OutgoingReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null)
        return;
    String phoneNumber = null;

    // Incoming call
    String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if ((state != null)
            && (state
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))) {
        phoneNumber = bundle
                .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        System.out.println("in coming number :-" + phoneNumber);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);

        Button btnTag = new Button(context);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("phone No " + phoneNumber);
        btnTag.setId(1);
        ll.addView(btnTag);

    }
    // Outgoing call
    else if (state == null) {
        phoneNumber = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        System.out.println(" out going number :-" + phoneNumber);
          LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);

          Button btnTag = new Button(context); btnTag.setLayoutParams(new
          LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); btnTag.setText("phone No " +
          phoneNumber); btnTag.setId(111111);
        ll.addView(btnTag);

    }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
09-26 10:46:20.255: I/System.out(274):  out going number :-7875851207
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274): Activity com.cssl.core.CustomOutgoingCallActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.cssl.core.OutgoingReciver@44ee7610 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.cssl.core.CustomOutgoingCallActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.cssl.core.OutgoingReciver@44ee7610 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(ActivityThread.java:939)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.getReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:734)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:791)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:778)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:772)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:318)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at com.cssl.core.CustomOutgoingCallActivity.onCreate(CustomOutgoingCallActivity.java:18)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-26 10:46:57.076: E/ActivityThread(274):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 10:47:02.566: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(274): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-26 10:47:08.676: I/System.out(274):  out going number :-0377778888
09-26 10:47:25.496: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1681 objects / 127448 bytes in 210ms
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Plz check I have posted @Bobbake4